# Selecting rows in data.table by expression on a character column name

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to subset a `data.table` by an expression involving a column, but I only have the column name as a character string.

My `data.table` is

```
DT = data.table(a=c(1,0,1))
```

I would like to do

```
DT[a==1]
```

but I only have the column name "a" specified as a string. So far I am achieving the desired result by doing

```
DT[ DT[['a']]==1 ]
```

but is there a more idiomatic way of achieving the same result? I notice that `DT[eval('a==1')]` throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are passing an expression, use `parse`

```
DT[eval(parse(text = 'a==1'))]
```

---

If the column name is the only one specified as a string

```
col1 <- "a"
DT[eval(as.symbol(col1)) == 1]
```

Or to a less extent `get` (not recommended though as it can lead to envir issues if not properly used)

```
DT[get(col1) == 1]
#   a
#1: 1
#2: 1
```

---

Another option is to make use of `.SDcols`

```
DT[DT[, .SD[[1]] == 1,.SDcols = col1]]
#   a
#1: 1
#2: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with a generic expression and a column name, you can use `as.name` and substitute to compose the final expression:

```
# helper function
subx = function(ex0, x_nm) 
  do.call(substitute, list(ex0, list(x = as.name(x_nm))))

# usage
ex = subx(quote(x == 1), "a")
DT[eval(ex)]
```

This approach -- composing the final expression and then calling `eval` inside `DT[...]` -- allows data.table to parse the expression and use any optimization (for example, in this case of filtering with `==`, "auto-indexing" might be used).